# Safari 5 on Mac hangs on uploading files

Tags: php, apache, macos, file-upload, safari

I have a user who is using the latest version of OSX and Safari. When he tries to upload a file through a form, it hangs (spinner spinning) but nothing happened. I did some reasearch and found this:

http://airbladesoftware.com/notes/note-to-self-prevent-uploads-hanging-in-safari

This fixed problems in previous versions of Safari, but obviously not Safari 5.

I was wondering if anyone else has any ideas how to resolve this? There was some mentioned of it being related to persistent http connections (thus the fix above) and I am using PHP (but I don't think that matters).

Comment: is it possible to show some code ? that would give kind of idea.

Comment: Oddly, I've noted this problem in the past (with ZenPhoto uploads) but only when using a particular version of MAMP on a local server. I wonder if it's specific to a version of Apache, or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had some success sending the connection: close header to solve this issue.

Add

```
 header("connection: close");
```

to the code that handles the file upload. It doesn't seem to solve the issue 100% but it certainly improves it. note that it's case sensitive: "Connection: close" won't work.

Comment: Hi Stephen, just to calrify, is this something to put at the very end of PHP execution?

Comment: no, it should work anywhere, so long as it's before any output (i.e. echo statements or dropping back to HTML mode) occurs.

Comment: This worked to an extent. What I did is use the header above as the 'ajax' call referenced above.

Answer (score 2):

Well I found out that in my case the issue is definitely depending on the file content. When uploading a particular JPG file it fails in 8 from 10 attempts (Safari 5.5.1, but here's the seldom case where IE does a better job;-).

When loading and exporting the JPG file with Mac's Preview creating a new JPG fixes the problem disappears. Unfortunately nothing that helps to fix the problem but maybe worth to give Safari users a hint.