# Safari hangs when uploading files

Tags: html, file-upload, safari, html-input

When uploading files to our PHP application through Safari, it starts uploading them and, after a bit, it hangs without proceeding. The request then goes in timeout and a 500 is reported.
Trying again and again, the uploads hangs always at the same percentage.

The script is very simple as you can see:

```
<?php print_r($_FILES); ?>
<form action="?" enctype='multipart/form-data' method="post">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**The problem occurs always trying to upload a very large number of files (over 3500) in a multiple file input**.

We already tried to close the connection as suggested by the [Safari 5 on Mac hangs on uploading files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955536/safari-5-on-mac-hangs-on-uploading-files) post without success.

Maybe is a bug of Safari. I opened a bug report as you can see on [OpenRadar](http://openradar.appspot.com/30701082), but different solutions or workarounds are welcomed.

Have you ever got the same problem? Thank you for your help!

---

**UPDATE**

Seems not a PHP issue: the upload hangs before sending the request to the server, so before processing the script.

The current php.ini has this configuration:

```
[PHP]
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_time = 600
max_input_vars = 100000
memory_limit = 2G
post_max_size = 512M
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 512M
max_file_uploads = 100000
```

and Fcgi the following:

```
IPCCommTimeout 601
FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
```

Answer (score 0):

this is bug which nobody knows how to resolve or how to fix

Answer (score -1):

Easy. Just limit Safari users to single uploads. Provide them with a popup telling them they are limited to single uploads because Safari sucks and no one should use it for anything.